# Log out hook not working in OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, bash

I have a simple script I that I need to run on logout or when the computer is shut off. The script simply deletes any saved network passwords from the keychain.

```
#!/bin/bash
#delete any saved network passwords
/usr/bin/security delete-generic-password -D "802.1X Password"
```

After creating the script and saving it in the root directory as "cleanupnetwork.sh", I ran the following terminal commands:

```
sudo chmod u+x cleanupnetwork.sh
sudo chmod 700 cleanupnetwork.sh
sudo /usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook /cleanupnetwork.sh
```

When I log out and log back in, the network password is still in the keychain, but if I run the script directly, it deletes the password from the login keychain.

I'm new to scripting, so I'm not sure why this isn't working. I suspect some sort of permissions or path issue, but I'm not sure how to even begin to fix it.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

From the [developer doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CustomLogin.html)

> Note: If no plist file exists for com.apple.loginwindow, this method
>   will not work. This file
>   (/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist) does not
>   exist on a fresh installation until the user changes a login window
>   setting (such as turning on fast user switching).

So,

- try enable *fast user switching* in the System Preferences. (You can disable it after, the plist file should remain in place). You can check it with

```
sudo ls -l /var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist
```

- double check the `/path/to/cleanupnetwork.sh` - it is really in the `/`?